# Excel doesn't recognize imported date/time as date and time when there is a leading "0" in the millisecond spot

Tags: excel, date, excel-formula, excel-2016

I'm trying to import data from a text file that has date/time and current values. It imports as `yyyy/mm/dd hh/mm/ss 000`. Excel recognizes most of these as dates, but when there is a "0" in the front of the millisecond spot, it doesn't recognize it as a date. If I delete the 0 or change it to a different number it recognizes it.

My data set is huge (200,000+ column length) so manually turning these into dates isn't feasible. Is there any way to make excel recognize the dates with leading zeroes as dates? Either in the workbook or VBA? Using 2016.

**Text File Data Set**

[image: Text File Data Set]

**Excel File Data Set**

[image: Excel File Data Set]

Comment: Can you please post the *Text File Data Set* sample data as text too instead of an image? So people here have some data to reproduce it? • How did you import the CSV? Manually or by VBA code? If you did it with VBA please add your code to the question itself.

Answer (score 2):

You could import the datetimes as text, then in another column add a formula to change the second space into a decimal point and convert it to a datetime:

```
=DATEVALUE(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ",".",2))+TIMEVALUE(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ",".",2))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

1. Import your data into Excel.
2. Split text to columns by comma and space this will result in 4 columns

   ```
       A      |      B     |   C   |    D
   7/12/2018  |  16:18:05  |   91  |  -0.26
   7/12/2018  |  16:18:05  |  291  |  -0.25
   ```
3. Use this formula in column E

   ```
   =A:A+B:B+(C:C/24/60/60/1000)
   ```
4. Format column E as

   ```
   DD/MM/YYYY hh:mm:ss.000
   ```

   or something similar. The tricky part here is `hh:mm:ss.000`

Comment: I tried the `YYYY/MM/DD hh:mm:ss 000` and it gave me an unrecognizable format in 2013.  However when adding the decimal point instead of the space to separate milliseconds it works without issue

Comment: @ForwardEd the space doesn't work because there is no variable for milliseconds. So milliseconds can only be displayed as a fraction of seconds. And decimal separator is `.` or `,` (depending on localization). So that's why it must be `ss.000` or `ss,000`.

Answer (score 0):

If you import using Power Query, you can

- Split column 1 by delimiter specifying `space` as the delimiter and Right-most delimiter in the options

  - Ensure the data type of the resulting column 2 is Text
- Then Merge columns 1 & 2 with dot specified as the separator
- Ensure the data type of the merged column is Date/Time
- Check to ensure the data type of the last column is Decimal
- Load the results to the worksheet, and format as you like.

Once you have set up the query, you can refresh it whenever your data changes.